# How to "play with friends" with more than 10 players

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was trying to set up a game with 12 players. But the play with friends lobby would not let more than 10 players join. How can i set up a game with more than 10 players

Comment: Set up a server and let the 12 people join your server through Steam.

Comment: You need this server online or lan?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up your own server at [crosshairgenerator.com](http://crosshairgenerator.com/featured/setup-a-dedicated-server-on-counter-strike/)
2. Set `maxplayers` to what ever you like in the `gamemodes_server.txt` file.
3. Have fun

Note: in the command line of your server you can use `maxplayers_override [#]` to change the number during a game

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to host your own server then you could change the game mode to casual. However it won't be as fun. I would recommed setting up your own server and use this as a single conditions option. The reasons that I wouldnt personally is because I would have to mess around with my port settings and I probably will make a mistake and then I will get hacked (not really but you get my point)